# How to converting Wikipedia Article to RSS Feed item

Tags: python, mediawiki, web-scraping, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Problem statement: 
A python script should be created to generate the rss feed of Wikipedia's Featured Articles for several languages.

English rss feed [exists](http://toolserver.org/~skagedal/feeds/fa.xml) I need to create similar for other languages. Generation of English rss is pretty easy using the url structure of this type of urls http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Today%27s_featured_article/August_29%2C_2011

But for the other languages I should scrape the data from Wiki page manually, so how this can be done ? Are there any already existing Wiki Page to RSS feed converters ?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't convert the wiki page. I would convert the english rss, take feedparser to get the feed. Convert it with your favorite langauge api then send it back out using twisted to serve the rss feed.

Comment: This __is__ opinion but its valid advice.

Comment: In my case this will not make sense as the aim is to have rss feeds for every language. As a result the same article my not exist for two different languages.